# MongoDB - return subdocument of large parent

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of large documents (between ~200 - ~500 kb each).

Each document contains an array of subdocuments. Within each subdocujent, there is an array i need to search through.

I need to build an interface that enables me to fetch a single subdocument.

Considering the fact that i can not refactor the document model and do not know in which parent document the target lives, what would be the smartest and fastest way to achieve this?

I would like to give you an example of what I have tried, but I am even struggling with the basic concept of "How do I search each array of subdocuments for what I need", so excuse the lack of such.

A parent document looks like this:

```js
{
"name":"Foobar",
"subs":[
    {           
        "imageName":"name",
        "foreignNames":[
            {
                // This is the field I need to search through
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: You could add one (shorted)demo-Document to show the schema of an Object. `db.collection.findOne()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is a distinct difference between returning a document and just the selected "sub-document" detail, and you have nested arrays, your best approach is to use the [**`aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method instead:

So if consider the following document as a sample:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5380709ab5caa8c27c8a1392"),
    "name" : "Foobar",
    "subs" : [
        {
            "imageName" : "name",
            "foreignNames" : [
                {
                    "tagname" : "value"
                },
                {
                    "tagname" : "notvalue"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then the aggregate statement is:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Actually match the documents containing the matched value
    { "$match": {
        "subs.foreignNames.tagname": "value"
    }},

    // Unwind both of your arrays
    { "$unwind": "$subs" },
    { "$unwind": "$subs.foreignNames" },

    // Now filter only the matching array element
    { "$match": {
        "subs.foreignNames.tagname": "value"
    }},

    // Group back one level of data         
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "name": "$name",
            "imageName": "$subs.imageName"
        },
        "foreignNames": { "$push": "$subs.foreignNames" }
    }},

    // Group back to the original level
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "name": { "$first": "$_id.name" },
        "subs": {
            "$push": { 
                "imageName": "$_id.imageName",
                "foreignNames": "$foreignNames"
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

And the result will be:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5380709ab5caa8c27c8a1392"),
    "name" : "Foobar",
    "subs" : [
        {
            "imageName" : "name",
            "foreignNames" : [
                {
                    "tagname" : "value"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The advantage in there is that if you are possibly going to have more than one match and even on more than one level, so say additional items in "subs", then this will actually keep them all together for you while filtering results that do not match out.

If you don't actually need that and only want that particular "document" or only specific fields in the document as a whole, then you can shorten that at the [**$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages and just [**$project**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) the results you need:

```js
db.newdoc.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "subs.foreignNames.tagname": "value"
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$subs" },
    { "$unwind": "$subs.foreignNames" },
    { "$match": {
        "subs.foreignNames.tagname": "value"
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "matched": "$subs.foreignNames"
    }}
])
```

As an example, but that will return:

```js
{ "matched" : { "tagname" : "value" } }
```

So that is pretty much the way to handle things.

**Note**: Just before you ask, as many do, why that [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) statement is made twice during the pipeline, it is sort of explained in the comments but here's the point.

Even if there was only 1 document in a collection of 10,000 documents that actually had the inner array document with the matching condition it makes sense to do this [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) before you are doing any of this array unwinding.

This is simply because even if you are going to filter this later down to 1 result, what you do not want to do is [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) all of the 10,000 documents with their arrays into possibly 100,000 or more entries and then search through that to find that 1. You want to reduce that to the smallest possible set and discard any document that was never going to contain the sub-document you want.

Additionally, as has been mentioned, using [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) at the initial stage of an aggregation pipeline is the **only** chance you get to select an index in order to improve your query performance. Once you start de-constructing/re-constructing the document, indexes are no longer available.

So index first, ie:

```js
db.collection.ensureIndex({ "subs.foreignNames.tagname": 1 })
```

Comment: Do I get it right that this only computes the complete parent document instead of returning only that field? So I could do it just as well at the front-end?

Comment: @user2422960 Must have missed your comment here. That was not the intent. There were some small problems in the original post but I have fixed those up and added a better explanation of what is going on here.

Answer (score 1):

This will search all Documents in the Array `foreignNames` for the tag `tagname` (replace this with tag you want to check) with the value `value`.

```
db.collection.find({"subs.foreignNames.tagname":"value"})
```

you could add an Index for this search with the following command. More about Indexes (and limitation) can be found in [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-types/).

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({"subs.foreignNames.tag":1})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The request made this way takes a lot of time to complete. I am aware that I could set up indexes, but I neither were able to find an understandable instruction to this, nor do I know if indexes are the only way to increase performance. Any help on this would be appreciated :)